# why laravel livewire wire:model wire:click not work when every thing set right?

Tags: php, laravel, button, click

livewire work and render the component with data successfully , but wire:mode or wire:click button
not work .
I read all documents and questions about why wire not working in web
I do all thing .
even a simple html like below not work (all elements in one div),

```
<html>

<head>

   @livewireStyles
</head>

<body>
@livewire('orderbuybuy')

@livewireScreipts

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of `@livewireScripts`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>

   @livewireStyles
</head>

<body>
@livewire('orderbuybuy')

@livewireScripts

</body>

</html>
```